# chromium code that won't be run in unit test

Tags: chromium

I am adding some code to Chromium code base for debugging purpose. I want to these code to be run by chromium only, meaning not be executed by gtest's browser tests. Is there a flag to inform Browser tests to skip that part of code?

Thanks